# Should omnibus answers be split?

Tags: discussion

In a comment to [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/18821/696), I asked @aramis if he thought his answer should be split. He replied that he didn't want to. Instead of continuing the discussion in comments, I thought it was time to move this to meta.

Because what I really started to wonder was if splitting answers like that (not just his, all of them, mine included) would be better for **the site**, for the reasons I gave in the comment: more granular voting and better differentiation of good answer "segments" from bad.

Comment: Note that [game rec questions are not on topic](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/5747/23970); this Q&A comes from a time on the site when they were allowed.

Answer (score 14):

I'm not a fan at all of the "one game per answer" thing that is common in forums. It trivializes the idea of recommendations. TBH a good game rec answer probably has several games listed as either the requirements are too general to fit just a game or two, there are multiple games that fit the requirements, or there are different aspects of the requirements that different games perform better in.

Omnibus answers are complete answers, I'd rather not see answers made *less* complete just to satisfy some arbitrary standard of granularity in voting.

Comment: I agree here - complete and concise omnibus answers are likely to attract good votes.  Incomplete or waffling answers are likely to attract less votes.  No need to complicate things with dozens of answers to a single question.

Comment: there's also the point of how do you choose one correct answer if you split them up?

Comment: you go with the answer that contains what worked for you, possibly commenting about what worked and what didn't.

Comment: Despite my comment there, I agree with @Gaxx: I upvote good omnibus answers that feel like they're complete and integral, and I ignore omnibus answers that read like a bunch of unrelated thoughts, and downvote the rare ones that are really disjointed. I think it's good guidance to answerers to *consider* whether an answer is better together or split, but I don't think mandating it is required or useful. The difference will always be subjective, so it really *has* to be left up to individual answerer/voter judgement.